# Data.frame, apply a function to subset of columns while passing multiple arguments to the function

Tags: r, dataframe, arguments

I have a dataframe with hundreds of columns and I would like to set the values of some of those columns based on another column.

```
project <- c(1,2,3)
team <- c('john,bob', 'bob,gary', 'larry')
john <- c('john','john','john')
bob <- c('bob','bob','bob')
gary <- c('gary','gary','gary')
larry <- c('larry','larry','larry')
df <- data.frame(project,team,john,bob,gary,larry)

  project     team john bob gary larry
1       1 john,bob john bob gary larry
2       2 bob,gary john bob gary larry
3       3    larry john bob gary larry
```

I'd like to apply a function to the columns `df[,3:ncol(df)]`.
The function should compare the value of each name column to the team column and set the value to 1 if there is a match

```
project      team  john  bob  gary  larry  ...
      1  john,bob     1    1     0      0  ... 
      2  bob,gary     0    1     1      0  ...
      3     larry     0    0     0      1  ...
```

I can apply a function to the correct columns, but I'm not sure how to pass in the value of my team column to the function.

```
df[,3:ncol(df)] <- sapply(df[,3:ncol(df)],function(x) ifelse(grepl(x, df$team),1,0)
```

It is throwing the following error:

> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Comment: Your code works fine, but you're passing an entire column as a pattern to `grepl` which raises a warning. If you just select the first element of the column (if your data is structured as above), the warnings go away and it works fine: `df[,3:ncol(df)] <- sapply(df[,3:ncol(df)],function(x) ifelse(grepl(x[1], df$team),1,0))`.

Comment: And really, warnings don't _stop_ anything; they just sometimes let you know it's not doing what you want. In this case, it uses the first element as the pattern, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mapply` and overwrite:

```
df[-(1:2)] <- mapply(grepl, pattern=names(df)[-(1:2)], x=list(df$team))+0
df
#  project     team john bob gary larry
#1       1 john,bob    1   1    0     0
#2       2 bob,gary    0   1    1     0
#3       3    larry    0   0    0     1
```

The `list(df$team)` ensures that you don't get problems with lengths of each object as the `pattern=` for each column is searched across the entire `x=` vector.

Answer (score 1):

As the columns from 3 have only a single value, we can just `split` the 'team' column, use `mtabulate` to get the count and replace the columns in 'df' with the new result.

```
library(qdapTools)
d1 <- mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df$team), ","))
df[names(df)[-(1:2)]] <- d1[names(df)[-(1:2)]]
df
#   project     team john bob gary larry
#1       1 john,bob    1   1    0     0
#2       2 bob,gary    0   1    1     0
#3       3    larry    0   0    0     1
```

---

Instead of `mtabulate`, we can also use the `table` from `base R`.

```
 d1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(
         table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df$team), ","), 
                  df$project))[2:1]))
```

and then replace the columns in 'df' as above.

Comment: I got another answer to work but will try this for my own edification later.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3507235 No problem, thelatemail's answer is the one relevant for this question.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple with `grepl` given that your name vectors are all the same within columns:

```
df[ ,3:ncol(df)] <- lapply(df[ ,3:ncol(df)] , function(x) as.numeric(grepl(x, df$team) )  )
Warning messages:
1: In grepl(x, df$team) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In grepl(x, df$team) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In grepl(x, df$team) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In grepl(x, df$team) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

# the warnings didn't affect the outcome adversely.
> df
  project     team john bob gary larry
1       1 john,bob    1   1    0     0
2       2 bob,gary    0   1    1     0
3       3    larry    0   0    0     1
```

If you wnat the warnings to go away just use the "top" value in each column for the logical match:

```
df[ ,3:ncol(df)] <- lapply(df[ ,3:ncol(df)] , 
                           function(x) as.numeric(grepl(x[1], df$team) )  )
```